# pl/sql conditionally replace characters of field in a table using regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Using ORACLE sql developer
I have:
Field ID 1: '006789'
Field ID 2: '026789'
Field ID 3: '126789'

I want:
Field ID 1: '6789'
Field ID 2: '26789'
Field ID 3: '126789'

This lives in table "EMPLOYEES"

I want to do something like this

```
begin
if FIELD_ID is like '00%' then
        update EMPLOYEES 
        set FIELD_ID = %s/\%1c..//
elseif FIELD_ID is like '0%' then
        update EMPLOYEES 
        set FIELD_ID = %s/\%1c.// 
endif;
```

I'm really new to procedures and regex (obviously).

Comment: `nvl(ltrim(field_id,'0'),'0')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to remove leading or trailing characters from a string, you don't need regex, TRIM functions wil suffice. In Oracle, there
are three functions, [TRIM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions229.htm#SQLRF06149), [LTRIM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions103.htm#SQLRF00664) and [RTRIM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions169.htm#SQLRF06104).

To answer your question, either

```
ltrim(field_id,'0')
```

or

```
trim(leading '0' from field_id)
```

should work.

Also, note that there a subtle difference between TRIM and LTRIM/RTRIM. TRIM can take only one trim character, while RTRIM/LTRIM can take many.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single update statement like,

```
UPDATE employees set field_id = ltrim(field_id, '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure why did you go with RegExp, but if you need just removing Leading and Trailing character from string Oracle has TRIM function for that.

***TRIM(both '1' from '123Tech111') would return '23Tech'***

[example that fits your requirement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php)

[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but another option (since the source data is a number with leading zeros) you could convert the string to a number and then back to a string something like: `to_char(to_number(field_id))`

Here's an example:

```
WITH TST_DATA AS (
    SELECT '006789' FIELD_ID  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '026789' FIELD_ID  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '126789' FIELD_ID  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(FIELD_ID)) FIELD_ID 
FROM TST_DATA
;
FIELD_ID
6789
26789
126789
```